# Returning a std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

It is okay for a private `std::unique_ptr` member of a class to be retrieved as
a raw pointer via `get()`?

Example class:

```
class png {
public:
    png(const std::string& fname);
    png(const png&);
    png();

    png& operator=(png);

    ~png();

    void read(const std::string& fname);

    inline bool is_valid() {
        return m_val;
    }

    const unsigned char* getData() const;

private:
        std::unique_ptr<char> m_data;  // m_data is its image data
```

Retrieval function

```
const unsigned char* png::getData() const
{
    return m_data.get();
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask?  Are you having problems with your program? Instead of [guessing at the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806), you should describe what the actual problem is.  It might end up being something completely different to what you think.

Comment: @paddy. actually i am trying to code a third party image lib to handl image I/O or at least to load into memory for use with zxing-cpp (https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp)

Comment: That is irrelevant and does not answer either of the two things I asked you.

Comment: I think you meant to use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead. In which case you could use `std::vector<char>`. Also, `char` isn't very good for raw binary bytes, as it might be signed which could lead to problems. Better use e.g. `uint8_t` or `std::byte`.

Comment: @paddy Maybe you are right.. i should ask a better question... perhaps could close this question

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite OK, since pointer to `char` doesn't implicitly convert to a pointer to `unsigned char`.

In general however, it can be OK to return a non-owning pointer to an object owned by a unique pointer.

P.S. It is somewhat wasteful to allocate a single char dynamically.

Comment: It'd be better to return by reference so the ownership is clear.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Only if the pointer can be guaranteed to be non-null.

Comment: That's right, but a `char*` looks a lot like a string, so I am not sure of this design in general.

Comment: Also note that OP is trying to convert `char*` to `unsinged char*` implicitly, which won't compile.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Good point. I've edited the answer accordingly.